# Async/Await with JQuery document READY

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, jquery-3

It works with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {})` but I am curious of making it work with JQuery.

And also, I want with Async/Await, **not promises** because later I will need the variable outside of promise callback.

```
let products = [];

$(document).ready(async function() {      // Does not work with ASYNC
    await getProducts();                  // IF i dont use async await, products = empty
    products.forEach(product => console.log(product))
})

const getProducts = () => {
   // Ajax call to server
   // products = ajaxResult;              // asign variable to result
   // returns Promise;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"does not work"_? Also... _"later I will need the variable outside of promise callback"_ async / await does not solve this problem for you

Comment: 1. if I use ASYNC next to function, it does not run at all. 2. I mean I will need the products variable several time later on in the program. So I want it to be assigned first and then use it easily without using getProducts().then()

Comment: Works fine here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/d40cjmfL/

Comment: @Phil I checked my JQuery, its version is 3.2.1. Can it be because of that?

Comment: Seems you've found the issue, it fails to work on JSFIddle with that version too. Works with 3.3.1 onwards. Problem reproduced here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/d40cjmfL/2/

Comment: It's 2021, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). There shouldn't be any harm upgrading though

Comment: @Phil You are right but the whole project is done on JQuery already. It will take time to reproduce everything into Vanilla JS. Yet, thank you for your time, Phil.

Comment: @Phil regarding your link to might not need jQuery, did you see how every jquery selector is just $(el) but right for each type of element it is different? I would like to call that article `you might need jQuery after all` BTW I have migrated from jQuery 1 to 3 more than I can count to downgrade it back due to hundreds of tickets from customers complaining at least one feature is broken. The only thing that I use jQuery is its selectors and `$(function(){ .... })` (no animation, no Ajax ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was due to JQuery version 3.2.1 and maybe in some lower versions as well. `$(document).ready(async function() {})`
is fine to be used in later versions however.

> `$(document).ready( handler )` **is deprecated as @Phil mentioned below.**
>
> `$(handler)` **is recommended to use instead. [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler)**

Comment: FYI the `$(document).ready( handler )` syntax is deprecated. The advice in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler) is to use `$( handler )`

Comment: @Phil Yes, thanks, I forgot to mention it.