# google.script.run function won't write to JavaScript global variable using await

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, async-await, global-variables

I have been having trouble lately with global variables as well as using async functions like "await" (which I am new to) in Javascript with Apps Script.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
let patientData = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadPatientData(); //I want to wait for this to complete

  google.script.run.logThis(patientData.names); //Returns null
})

async function loadPatientData() {

  //Get the data from an array in the .gs file, pass it to variable "a"
  const a = await new Promise(r => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(r).getPatientData();
  });

  //Pass that data to global variable
  //If I log patientData.names here, it returns with the array data
  patientData.names = a;
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to wait for the google.script.run.withSuccessHandler function to complete and then pass the resulting array data to my patientData.names variable. As seen with my comments in the code, the array is passed to the global variable inside loadPatientData(), but not in (document).ready().

getPatientData() returns an array.

Right now I am logging this with a function in my .gs file called logThis() which just uses Logger.log() to print data to the Execution Log.

patientData.names comes back as null in the Execution Log. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just write to it in the Success Handler?

Comment: You should `await`: `loadPatientData();` like `await loadPatientData();` inside a `async` function(i.e., the `ready` function should also be `async`)

Comment: I changed the line to "$(document).ready(async function() {" and added "await" before calling loadPatientData(). The next line where logThis is called does not run

Comment: @Nick What makes you think it doesn't run?

Comment: I thought it didn't run because nothing came up in the Execution Log.

Comment: Add a alert: `alert('about to call logThis')` before the `google.script.run` call

Comment: I added that and refreshed the page and no alert showed. hmmmm. I also put one in front of "await loadPatientData();" and no alert showed.

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: Using jquery version 2.2.4

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984453/ Use latest version or don't use jquery at all.

Comment: My apologies. I was unaware that I wasn't using the latest version. Thank you for your time and help it is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling function  also needs to be `async`:

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
  await /*I want to wait for this to complete => so wait*/loadPatientData();
  google.script.run.logThis(patientData.names); //Returns good
})
```